# How to load a file containing gherkin variables instead of writing the variables in robotframework test

Tags: robotframework, gherkin

I am currently using gherkin typography in robot framework to run a scenario as follows (it works):

```
*** Test Cases ***
Scenario: compute my data
    [Template]  Scenario Outline: compute my data
    origin1    SVA1000    NR
    origin2    SVA2000    NR2

*** Keywords ***
Scenario Outline: compute my data
    [Arguments]  ${origin}  ${reportingGroup}  ${report}
    Given print it ${origin} ${reportingGroup} ${report}


print it ${origin} ${reportingGroup} ${report}
    Log To Console    ${origin} ${reportingGroup} ${report}
```

I have a large amount of data, so i want to put my variables in a .txt file:

```
origin1    SVA1000    NR
origin2    SVA2000    NR2
```

**QUESTION : How to load a file containing the variables instead of writing the variables in the robot code?**

Comment: if you do not want to modify your file data file, you could write custom importer for robotframework-datadriver -  https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this section "[Resource and variable files](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-and-variable-files)". Create a python file and create a list to store your variables.

My solution:

`variables.py`

```
list =  [
            ["origin1","SVA1000","NR"],
            ["origin2","SVA2000","NR2"]
        ]
```

`main.robot`

```
*** Settings ***
Variables    variables.py

*** Test Cases ***
Scenario: compute my data
    FOR    ${data}    IN    @{list}
        FOR    ${data_0}    ${data_1}    ${data_2}    IN    @{data}
            Scenario Outline: compute my data    ${data_0}    ${data_1}    ${data_2}
        END
    END

*** Keywords ***
Scenario Outline: compute my data
    [Arguments]  ${origin}  ${reportingGroup}  ${report}
    Given print it ${origin} ${reportingGroup} ${report}


print it ${origin} ${reportingGroup} ${report}
    Log To Console    ${origin} ${reportingGroup} ${report}
```

Out put:

```
==============================================================================
Main
==============================================================================
Scenario: compute my data                                             origin1 SVA1000 NR
origin2 SVA2000 NR2
Scenario: compute my data                                             | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Main                                                                  | PASS |
1 test, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, however using lists only moves the problem !_!

Comment: @AlexisLeloup If you mean load some data to create a python list. I have done it before by python. But my data is stored in excel and through Python extract data into JSON format. Then it can be easy to create lots of data into a list in python.

Comment: Depends on your data where you store in what datatype. It has many ways to do it.

Comment: Finally, i parse my text file :
def parse_gherkin_text_file(path):
    """
    Parse file contains gherkin list of variables to 2dim list of element.
    :param path: path of file to parse
    :return:2dim list of element
    """
    f = open(path, "r")
    file_as_list = [x.strip().split("#", 1)[0] for x in f.readlines()]
    f.close()
    return [x.split() for x in file_as_list if x]

Then i use YOUR loop on it thanks ;) 
But I am still waiting for a "clean" answer

Comment: @AlexisLeloup Yes, I think your function is done what I said. But what is "clean" mean? Just use Robotframework syntax to do the above feature?

Comment: yes i want to know how to do this with only robot features